# Is there a ShouldBeEquivalentTo() alternative for NUnit assertions?

Tags: c#, nunit, assertions, assertion

Is there an alternative for Fluent Assertions' `ShouldBeEquivalentTo()` (or Machine.Specifications' `ShouldBeLike()`) in the NUnit (constraint-based) assertion framework?

I'm coming from the BDD-world and really liked this kind of assertions. Unfortunately, in my current project I'm not allowed to use a different (fluent) assertion library.

Would love any pointer to some NUnit extension supporting this method!

Comment: Do you mean the NUnit `Assert` class? `Assert.That(something, Is.EqualTo(expected));`?

Comment: Yes, `Assert.That()` (the constraint-based model).

Comment: There is also `CollectionAssert` but I don't think there is a full structural comparison in nunit, though I may be wrong.

Comment: I'm also grateful for any pointer to an extension (afaik the constraint-based model is extensible), e.g. to a NuGet package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround we use now is to convert both sides (the actual object and the anonymous expected object) into strings, e.g. by serializing them using JSON.NET.